# In Doom3's source code, why did they use bitshift to generate the number instead of hardcoding it?

Tags: c++

Why did they do this:

```
Sys_SetPhysicalWorkMemory( 192 << 20, 1024 << 20 );   //Min = 201,326,592  Max = 1,073,741,824
```

Instead of this:

```
Sys_SetPhysicalWorkMemory( 201326592, 1073741824 );
```

[The article I got the code from](http://fabiensanglard.net/doom3/index.php)

Comment: Probably considered it more readable/understandable. If you were going to use constants, you'd probably want to at least express them in hex.

Comment: Would *you* immediately recognise 201326592 as 192 Mi or 1073741824 as 1 Gi? It's impossible to tell at a glance how large those numbers are, or whether 201326592  is greater or smaller than 1073741824 - they just look random.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A neat property is that shifting a value `<< 10` is the same as multiplying it by 1024 (1 KiB), and `<< 20` is 1024*1024, (1 MiB).

Shifting by successive powers of 10 yields all of our standard units of computer storage:

- `1 << 10`  = 1 KiB ([Kibibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte))
- `1 << 20`  = 1 MiB ([Mebibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte))
- `1 << 30`  = 1 GiB ([Gibibyte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibibyte))
- ...

So that function is expressing its arguments to [`Sys_SetPhysicalWorkMemory`](https://dev.visucore.com/doom3/doxygen/win__shared_8cpp.html#ae613747e8f556c99908d6a03727f6020)`(int minBytes, int maxBytes)` as 192 MB (min) and 1024 MB (max).

Comment: Those are kibi and mebibytes, not kilo/mega.

Comment: @Pubby Thanks. I was actually in the process of changing that when you pointed it out :-) The whole world hasn't caught on to the unambiguity  that is the binary IEC binary prefixes yet, so thank you for suggesting it!

Comment: why not define a macro `#define MEGA_BYTE << 20`?

Comment: @Pubby, it's not at all uncommon for people to switch their definition of K/M depending on the context. The thing I find amusing is when people claim the disk manufacturers are "cheating" when they give capacity in G=1000000000 instead of G=1073741824; obviously they don't know their history.

Answer (score 12):

Self commenting code:

192 << 20 means 192 * 2^20 = 192 * 2^10 * 2^10 = 192 * 1024 * 1024 = 192 MByte

1024 << 20 means 1024 * 2^20 = 1 GByte

Computations on constants are optimized away so nothing is lost.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong (and I didn't study the source) , but I guess it's just for readability reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I think the point (not mentioned yet) is that

> All but the most basic compilers will do the shift at compilation time. Whenever you use operators with constant expressions, the
>   compiler will be able to do this before the code is even generated.
>   Note, that before constexpr and C++11, this did not extend to
>   functions.

Comment: Typically if you're going to quote something you should really cite/link to the source. Also, Eli did mention this exact thing.